# Using sendmail over SSH

Tags: ssh, sendmail, relay

I have a SSH access to the server with working `sendmail` provided by my hoster.
I want to configure my local `sendmail` to use remote server as a relay. How can I do that? Is it posiible at all?

Note: I can write script to run something like `ssh user@host sendmail ...` but it seems to me like there is a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Prepare SSH

Locally, create a new SSH key without password. In these examples, it will be located at `/etc/mail/ssh-sendmail-key` and owned by the `MAILUSER` user. **Change MAILUSER to whatever Unix account your local system uses: `postfix`, `sendmail`, `mail`, ... Using `root` or `nobody` is not recommended.**

```
# ssh-keygen -f /etc/mail/ssh-sendmail-key -N ""
# chown MAILUSER /etc/mail/ssh-sendmail-key{,.pub}
```

Append the contents of `/etc/mail/ssh-sendmail-key.pub` to the server's *authorized_keys* file:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA....
```

### Postfix

Create a `ssh` transport in `master.cf`:

```
ssh    unix    -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=MAILUSER argv=/usr/bin/ssh -i /etc/mail/ssh-sendmail-key myhostserver /usr/sbin/sendmail -i $recipient
```

In `main.cf`, add:

```
default_transport = ssh
```

### Exim

Router:

```
ssh:
    driver = manualroute
    domains = ! +local_domains
    transport = ssh
    route_list = * foo
```

Transport:

```
ssh:
    driver = pipe
    user = MAILUSER
    command = /usr/bin/ssh -i /etc/mail/ssh-sendmail-key myhostserver /usr/sbin/sendmail -i $RECIPIENT
```